# on/off switch with javascript in html

Tags: php, javascript, forms, templates, smarty

I have a code which has an on/off switch for disable/enable form inputs, but it doesn't works. My inputs are always off. What is the problem?

```
<script>  
   function DisEn(X){  
      if(X.checked)Allow=false;  
      else Allow=true;  
      document.A.T1.disabled=Allow;  
      document.A.T2.disabled=Allow;  
   }  
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <form name="A" >
      <span class="toggle-bg">
         <input type="radio" name="toggle" value="off" >
         <input type="radio" name="toggle" value="on">
         <span class="switch"></span>
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="T1" value="A" disabled>  
      <input type="text" name="T2" value="B" disabled>  
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Java **is not** JavaScript.

Comment: Yes,i made a mistake.

Comment: You're missing some var declarations and some {} for starters.

Comment: @Phillip:Could you explain more?I put some{}for graphic switch.

Comment: In JavaScript you need to put a `var` statement in front of each new variable you are declaring. Furthermore you need to wrap the execution part of your if else statements in {}.  I'd suggest you take a look at this, it's very helpful in making sure you know the basics of JavaScript.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FA_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code logic a bit, but it does the work.

### Source code

```
<script>  
   function DisEn(X){  
      document.A.T1.disabled=X;
      document.A.T2.disabled=X;
   }  
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <form name="A" >
      <span class="toggle-bg">
         <input type="radio" name="toggle" value="off" onClick="DisEn(false)">
         <input type="radio" name="toggle" value="on" onClick="DisEn(true)">
         <span class="switch"></span>
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="T1" value="A" disabled>  
      <input type="text" name="T2" value="B" disabled>  
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Final result

[image: Stuff in work]

### Explanation

When you click to one of the radio buttons it gives a boolean value to the `DisEn` function and sets the `disabled` parameter according to it.

Comment: :Now,i wanna to have a submit key and when i push that,if switch key was on the submit key pass a value=on(or value=1) and if was off pass a value=off(or value=0),because in the other page i have to know what was it,on or off

Comment: If you want to pass values to a totally new page, than have a look at HTTP POST and GET methods, maybe in PHP. Or you can use AJAX/JavaScript/JQuery to remove the form you used and add a new one.

Comment: I wanna to know in the other page,that my switch in my html page is on or off.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it, that doesn't involve using the inline onClick. For this reason, I moved the script to the end of the body tag, so that the elements are available in the DOM before we start messing with them in JavaScript. The code comments explains what is going on.

#### Vanilla JavaScript

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="A" >
<span class="toggle-bg">
<input type="radio" name="toggle" value="off" >
<input type="radio" name="toggle" value="on">
<span class="switch"></span>
</span>
<input type="text" name="T1" value="A" disabled>  
<input type="text" name="T2" value="B" disabled>  
</form>

<script>

// First, get a collection of the radio inputs with the name 'toggle'
var toggles = document.getElementsByName('toggle');

// Loop through each radio input with the name 'toggle' and add an event listener
// to each toggle input so it knows what to do when a user clicks it.
for (var i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {
    toggles[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        // Assign 'Allow' the value of the target. The target will be the radio
        // input that the user clicks. The value is simply the value you have set
        // above in your code - 'on' or 'off'.
        var Allow = event.target.value;

        // Check for the value of 'off' or 'on'
        if (Allow === 'off') {
            // Value is 'off', so disable the text inputs.

            // document.GetElementsByName() returns an array of elements. Because of this,
            // we have to use the [0] after we call it to get the first element in the array.
            // Because each element must have a unique name, this will grab the correct text
            // inputs to target.
            document.getElementsByName('T1')[0].disabled = true;
            document.getElementsByName('T2')[0].disabled = true;
        } else {
            // Value is 'on', so enable the text inputs.

            document.getElementsByName('T1')[0].disabled = false;
            document.getElementsByName('T2')[0].disabled = false;
        }

    }, false);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### jQuery Solution

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio[name=toggle]').click(function(event) {
        if (event.target.value == 'on') {
            $('input:text[name=T1], input:text[name=T2]').removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $('input:text[name=T1], input:text[name=T2]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="A" >
<span class="toggle-bg">
<input type="radio" name="toggle" value="off" >
<input type="radio" name="toggle" value="on">
<span class="switch"></span>
</span>
<input type="text" name="T1" value="A" disabled>  
<input type="text" name="T2" value="B" disabled>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This whole mess could be reduced to a few lines at most with jQuery--not to mention the document ready function.

Comment: @Phillip Yes, I agree 100%. The original post did not make any mention of jQuery so I did not bother to provide an answer that included jQuery as a requirement.